# Using user-made functions in MS Access queries to pass user variable values

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

In the past, I've been able to pass a variable from MS Access VBA to a query by creating a simple function which returns the value of the variable to the query via that function.  For example, to use the VBA variable named zvarApptID in a query, this sample VBA function allows that:

```
Public Function fvarApptID() As Long
    fvarApptID = zvarApptID
End Function
```

With this SQL using the zvarApptID VBA variable value:

```
SELECT MyApptID, MyName, MyAddress
FROM tblTable
WHERE MyID = fvarApptID
```

That has worked great until today, but admittedly I've added a new wrinkle to this scenario.  In this problematic scenario, I have a function (let's call it fDateOfVisitX) that returns a date value to the SQL query, but the code for fDateOfVisitX additionally sets the value of a VBA variable type long (let's call it zvarApptID) that returns a number value that I need to use in another field in the SQL query.  I have created a second function (let's use the fvarApptID function listed above) to return the value of zvarApptID to the SQL query to the other field.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblTherapists.TherapistID,
     tblTherapists.LastName AS ThxLastName,
     Format(datDueDateTime,"m/d/yyyy") AS ApptDate,
     fvarApptID() AS AppointmentID,
     fDateOfVisitX(tblTHerapist_X_Dispositions.DispositionID,3) AS datDueDateTime
FROM tblTherapists 
     LEFT JOIN tblTHerapist_X_Dispositions ON tblTherapists.TherapistID = tblTHerapist_X_Dispositions.TherapistID
WHERE tblTherapists.TherapistID = fvarTherapistID();
```

The problem is that the value returned to the SQL query by fvarApptID is always the PREVIOUS value of fvarApptID set by the PREVIOUS run of fDateOfVisitX.  Of course, that's not helpful because I need the current value from fvarApptID.

For example, if this is the data:

TherapistID  |  LastName  |  ApptDate  |  ApptID
10  |  Smithson  |  1/1/2018  |  10012
18  |  Cludgers  |  2/3/2018  |  10073
12  |  Almsoner  |  1/7/2018  |  10036

Here's what I want when fvarTherapistID returns a value of 18:
18  |  Cludgers  |  2/3/2018  |  **10073**

Here's what I get when fDateOfVisitX was run by the previous call when fvarTherapistID was 12:
18  |  Cludgers  |  2/3/2018  |  **10036**

Even though the *date* is correct, the value returned for *zvarApptID* is not correct for the date returned even though the zvarApptID is set in the fDateOfVisitX function *at the same time* the date is set (in fact, the zvarApptId is set first and then the next line of code sets the date that is returned by the fDateOfVisitX).

Changing the order of the items listed in the SELECT statement does not change the result.

If I run the same query a 2nd time without any other calls to fDateOfVisitX, the zvarApptID is then correct on the 2nd run (if only 1 row is returned by the SQL query).

I'm assuming this has something to do with the order in which the fields are collected by the SQL query, but I do not know how to force fvarApptID to be updated in the SQL at the correct time to get the correct value.

How do I get the correct fvarApptID value in the query result instead of the zvarApptID from the previous execution of fDateOfVisitX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use such kind functions in SQL, optimizer caches function value if it supposed to return the same value, so your function without parameters will be called just once, you can check this - just set breakpoint inside `fvarApptID`.
Workaround is simple: add a dummy parameter to your function:

```
Public Function fvarApptID(DummyParm as Variant) As Long
    fvarApptID = zvarApptID
End Function
```

and pass any changing value to this parameter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblTherapists.TherapistID,
     tblTherapists.LastName AS ThxLastName,
     Format(datDueDateTime,"m/d/yyyy") AS ApptDate,
     fvarApptID(tblTherapists.TherapistID) AS AppointmentID,
     fDateOfVisitX(tblTHerapist_X_Dispositions.DispositionID,3) AS datDueDateTime
```

In this case the function will be called for each selected row

Comment: This is such a helpful explanation, @Sergey S.  That makes sense and the suggested workaround also makes sense and works perfectly.  I suspect your answer will be helpful to other folks in the future.